# Passing an instance variable to a function

Tags: python, reference

Is there any way to pass a reference to a variable to an instance function to configure it?

For example, I want to set the value of `bar` to 1.0 using the `cofigure` method in the following class:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = 0.0
        self.configure(self.bar)
    def configure(self, var):
        var = 1.0

foo = Foo()
print(foo.bar)
```

I would expect `foo.bar` to be 1.0, but instead it is 0.0.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `var = ...` will always assign a value to a local variable `var`. It will never do anything other than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the actual attribute, assigning a parameter won't work (Python uses pass-by-value semantics for parameters). Here's how:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = 0.0
        self.configure(1.0)
    def configure(self, var):
        self.bar = var
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a few variables to configure and wanted to adhere to **DRY** principles so wanted to avoid this method. So there's no `inout` in python?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll re-think the structure.